# Include not finding library in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, glfw

I'm trying to move from Java to C++, but Visual Studio is giving me a huge pain... I have been trying every day for two weeks and nothing is working. Even though every include directory is set, Visual Studio can never find my glfw3.lib. Here, you can see the include directories set.
[image]

Here is another image showing that I include it in the linker.
[image]

One more image, showing that the file is where it should be. 
[image]

Despite everything looking correct, every time I compile I get an error that it  does not exist. I spent a while looking online too, never found anything that worked.

Comment: Have you tried an ordinary directory, not OneDrive?

Comment: Tried just putting it on my desktop. Still not working...

Comment: Please quote the exact error message(s).

Comment: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GLFW\glfw3.h': No such file or directory

Comment: Firstly, the title of your question is wrong. What's not found is a .h header file, not a .lib library. Secondly, the error hints that somewhere in the code there is an `#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>` which the compiler cannot resolve. This assumes that `glfw3.h` exists in a directory named `GLFW`, for example `X:\something\etc\GLFW`. Make sure that what you add to the `Include Directories` is just the base path, for example `X:\something\etc`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure you have use same configurations(Debug/Release) to build the
2. Add your library located folder in this place

[image]

**Edit:**

1. Search the file location of glfw3.h
2. Lest say the path of this file is `D:\mycode\project1\GLFW\glfw3.h`
3. Add `D:\mycode\project1\` path to the "Additional Include Directories" shown in this image

[image]

**Note:**
When I see your project property dialog box, I can see you are setting configurations for `All configurations`. Check left top corner of the images you posted.

But necessary configurations need to set for Debug and Release profiles separately. Specially library paths.

Comment: Tried building debug & release, which didn't fix it. Adding the directory to the additional library directories also didn't seem to work either.

Comment: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GLFW\glfw3.h': No such file or directory

Comment: Do you know where is the location fo glfw3.h file? if so please post the path. This is not related to library.

Comment: Check the Edit: part I have added to the answer

Answer (score 2):

A ".lib" file is *not* the same as a Java ".jar" archive. The ".lib" is compiled executable code.

The error you are receiving is because the compiler is looking for uncompiled ".h" files.

You need to locate the directory containing the "GLFW\glfw3.h" *header file* and point the include path at the directory housing the GLFW directory, not at the directory containing the ".lib".

The ".lib" file is not used by the *compiler* but the *linker*.

Answer (score 0):

Once all is set don't forget to select the platform(x86, x64) you want to compile your project to and make sure it matches your GLFW version.
If you don't do this then VS won't find GLFW source files.

Answer (score -3):

instead of using `#include<glfw3.h>` use `#include<GLFW/glfw3.h>`